# Traceback TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'. when try to delete columns and draw lines

Tags: python, opencv, draw

I want to delete some columns in my original image, and then draw a line (or rectangle or....). If I first draw the line and then drop the columns:

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)

cv2.line(img,pt1=(0,0),pt2=(711,711),color=(102, 255, 255),thickness=10)
img= np.delete(img,list(range(400,500)),1)

plt.imshow(img,"gray")
```

there is no problem. But when I first drop the columns and then draw a line (or rectangle or whatever..)

```
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg',0)


img= np.delete(img,list(range(400,500)),1)
cv2.line(img,pt1=(0,0),pt2=(711,711),color=(102, 255, 255),thickness=5)
plt.imshow(img,"gray")
```

Funny thing, this doesn't seem to be a problem with rows, and even making a copy the problem persist. Is not a problem of dimension and also try the ugly solution transposing

```
img= np.delete(img.T, list(range(400,500)),0),T
cv2.line(img,pt1=(0,0),pt2=(711,711),color=(102, 255, 255),thickness=5)
plt.imshow(img,"gray")
```

but again doesn't work.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you have `,T` at the end - and this creates `tuple`. Maybe you means `.T` to transform it.

Comment: How big is this image? Maybe you should change value in `pt2=(711,711)` into `pt2=(611,611)` if you deleted 100 columns.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Is not a problem os size, I tried other images and got the same error. In future questions I'll keep in mind your recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really strange situation.

`print(type(img))` before and after `np.delete()` shows `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>` so I don't know what makes problem.

But if I use `.copy()` then it works correctly.

```
img = np.delete(img, list(range(400,500)), 1).copy()
#img = np.delete(img.T, list(range(400,500)), 0).T.copy()
cv2.line(img, pt1=(0,0), pt2=(711,711), color=(102, 255, 255), thickness=10)
```

---

Maybe `np.delete()` is some "lazy" function which doesn't create new numpy directly but when it is needed but it doesn't do this when it is needed in `cv2.line()`

Maybe you should send this issue to authors of `numpy` or `cv2`

Comment: Really strange. I had tried almost the same but copying first 
`img0= img.copy()` and then deleting     `img0 = np.delete(img0, list(range(400,500)), 1)`.  (but not the two of them at the time), and didn't work, but your solution works. Thanks

Comment: you do `copy` BEFORE `delete` but I do `copy` AFTER `delete` and this is difference,

Comment: @furas Just experienced the same problem with `np.transpose()`, which required a `.copy()` after the `np.transpose()`. However, if I use `np.reshape()` instead of `np.transpose()`, no `.copy()` is required. :D